# Renew pfx file certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, pfx

I have bundled a pfx certificate within an application for a user, however now it appears that the certificate has been expired.

Is there anyway for me to renew the certificate on my side (server) without distributing the renewed certificate to the user ?

Comment: No, it would seriously undermine the whole idea of trust in  certificates for things that should stay secure...

Comment: @Rene: Thanks. I checked using openssl verify <pem-file> it says that my certificate has been expired. However when I installed the pfx in my Windows 7 through Certificate Import Wizard it shows that the valid  date is until 05/22/2012. Which one is correct?

Comment: Both are correct? In my timezone it is already past 22th of May 2012. The import wizard happily import any certificate. When the certificate is going to be used it will throw errors.

Comment: my bad, the expiry year is 2022.

Comment: Is the CA certificate expired?

Comment: add -verbose and -issuer_check to openssl verify http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/verify.html

Comment: There are two perm files in my cert folder (server-cert and ca-cert). I just checked both through openssl and found out that the server-cert valid up to 05/22/2022 while the ca-cert is valid until 8/12/2012. I believe the information shown in the Certificate Import Wizard picked up the server-cert. Anyway now I am certain that the client cert has been expired and I need create a new one with longer validity period. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'll summarize our conversation as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it would seriously undermine the whole idea of trust in certificates for things that should stay secure.

If you check your certificates with openssl verfify be sure to also add [-verbose and -issuer_check](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/verify.html)

Remember that for a certificate to be valid, all certificates in the chain (up to the Root CA) need to be valid and in the trusted CA store and not on a revocation list.

Comment: Is it possible to renew a certificate that is not yet expired, keeping the same private key on the CA? Without providing the private key of the end certificate for that operation?

Comment: @user987949 no, when a new certificate is generated they get a unique private/public key-pair. You can't preset the private key and if you could all security provided by SSL and other cryptography would be broken and useless.

Comment: I know that VeriSign e.g. can renew a valid certificate since they know you already have the right private key that was accepted once. It is true for other CAs as well.

What I would like to know is whether specifically in windows ADCS, there is an option to renew a certificate based on a valid certificate issued by that CA.